# Celery traceback encoding error

Tags: python, celery

I'm seeing this error in my Celery logs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/myproject/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 434, in trace_task
    uuid, retval, task_request, publish_result,
  File "/usr/local/myproject/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 152, in mark_as_done
    self.store_result(task_id, result, state, request=request)
  File "/usr/local/myproject/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/backends/amqp.py", line 129, in store_result
    delivery_mode=self.delivery_mode,
  File "/usr/local/myproject/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 169, in publish
    compression, headers)
  File "/usr/local/myproject/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 252, in _prepare
    body) = dumps(body, serializer=serializer)
  File "/usr/local/myproject/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 221, in dumps
    payload = encoder(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 35, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/myproject/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 54, in _reraise_errors
    reraise(wrapper, wrapper(exc), sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/local/myproject/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 50, in _reraise_errors
    yield
  File "/usr/local/myproject/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 221, in dumps
    payload = encoder(data)
  File "/usr/local/myproject/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 350, in pickle_dumps
    return dumper(obj, protocol=pickle_protocol)
EncodeError: can't pickle traceback objects
```

However, it doesn't list the Celery task. I'm assuming that some task is throwing an exception, and that Celery is then trying to capture and serialize the traceback as the task result, which isn't supported, and then throwing this additional exception, but without the task name, how do I discover the underlying problem?

I'm using celery==4.1.

Comment: can you touch source code where celery installed?

Comment: The error is can't pickle the objects, see if you have put pickle as one of the accepted content types. You can set this in celery configuration by adding pickle to  CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT . CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['pickle', 'json']